# Display fixed position element's child above absolutely positioned overlay

Tags: html, css

I have a layout containing two columns. The left column scrolls vertically and the right column is fixed. The right column contains multiple sections.

At some point, an overlay will be displayed. I want it to cover all content except for the first section in the right column (`<aside class="one">...</aside>`).

Right now, when the overlay is displayed it covers everything, including the `aside.one` element even though it has a higher z-index value.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- ... -->

<section id="sidebar">
    <aside class="one">...</aside>
    <aside class="two">...</aside>
</section>

<!-- ... -->

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
}

.one {
    z-index: 3;
}

.overlay {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle illustrating a more complete example of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ncSWz/10/

I know I will need to change some of my HTML structure to get this working, but I'm unsure exactly where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How important is IE support to you?

Comment: The more versions it supports the better, but it really only needs to  support the latest versions of all major browsers.

Comment: Shame. If you add `pointer-events:none;` to your overlay rules you can have the clicks pass right through the div. Unfortunately this won't work at all in any IE (except supposedly IE11). http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ncSWz/11/

Comment: The overlay should block all the content below it and only allow interaction with the element above it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's actually a bit of stacking context that's involved in this problem.

The idea is essentially, you need to have both the `.overlay` and `aside.one` in the same stacking context. You can accomplish that by moving the `.overlay` into the `#sidebar` (since it is `position: fixed` - this creates a stacking context).

Next, you need to create a couple more nested stacking contexts inside the sidebar. By changing the positioning on `aside.one` to `relative` and `.overlay` to `fixed`, you create another 2 stacking contexts that allow you to play with `z-index`ing of the elements.

Finally, you need to change the z-index on `#header` so that its below the overlay.

> - the root element (HTML),
> - positioned (absolutely or relatively) with a z-index value other than "auto",
> - elements with an [opacity value less than 1.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)
> - on mobile WebKit and Chrome 22+, position: fixed always creates a new stacking context, even when z-index is "auto"

Source: MDN: [The stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

**Updated jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ncSWz/17/

#### HTML

```
    <section id="sidebar">
        
        <!-- Should be on top of the overlay -->
        <aside class="one">...</aside>
        
        <aside class="two">...</aside>
        
        <!-- Should cover all elements except for aside.one -->
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </section>
```

#### CSS

```
header {
    z-index: 0;
}

...

.one {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
}

.overlay {
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `position: absolute` on both `one` and `two`, and set the top of `two`; since their parent is fixed, they're absolutely positioned to it.

<kbd>[**Running Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/ncSWz/15/)</kbd>

CODE ADDED

```
.one {
    position: absolute;
}

.two {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
}
```